# SpriteKit border all sides except bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

How do I create a border for the screen that will create a border around except for the bottom.

I am trying out `bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect` but it creates a border all around including the bottom. (which is the only part I don't want to be bordered)

```
SKPhysicsBody *borders = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
self.physicsBody = borders;
self.physicsBody.friction = 0.f;
```

I also tried `bodyWithEdgeFromPoint: toPoint` but still can't figure it out.

I also tried `bodyWithPolygonFromPath` but I didn't go too well. Any suggestions to do this? Other than making 3 nodes that will be placed on each border? top, left, right...

Comment: bodyWithEdgeFromPoint:toPoint: should work, you just need to add three of them for the 3 sides that should be blocked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a seemingly bottomless border edge body by resizing the rectangle you're using for the `bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect`:

```
float bottomOffset = 400.0;
CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0, -bottomOffset, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height+bottomOffset);
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:newFrame];
```

Now the rectangle's bottom is 400 points below the bottom edge of the screen, so your physics bodies will fall through the floor, if that's what you're after. Adjust as you see fit (e.g. add methods removing the nodes when they are below the bottom edge).

Comment: Note: remember to remove nodes that are off screen to improve performance!

Comment: Yes, that's what I said in the last sentence ;)

Comment: Oooops! :-) But it cannot be said often enough!